# JWT mobile and web login with different tokens

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, jwt

We have two client side application

1.Web app(Single page application).

2.Mobile (android and ios)

Both clients are powered by REST api (Express js) with JWT authentication.

My question about being login process.

1.When the user is logged in from mobile we return the JWT token for further api requests.

2.When user logged in from the web (already logged in mobile and issued a token) older token is replaced with new JWT token.
So the problem is  mobile login is invalidated because we uses the same JWT token for both (web and mobile)

How to keep track the separate logins for web and mobile in JWT.

Comment: You should not track anything: jwt should contain all the information necessary to identify a user. If you still for some reason must persist something additional in your database - you probably don't need JWT at all.

Comment: So keep JWT tokens in another table (or redis ) is a possible solution for this problem??

Comment: Why do you need JWT if you save it both server and client side? http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Comment: So how can i solve my issue ??build a custom authentication??

Comment: You have not explained the original problem you're solving, just your broken solution.

Comment: I want to keep serrate sessions for both web and mobile login users

Comment: So, create separate sessions for every user, regardless where they came from.

Comment: @zerkms if the user changes password don't we have to invalidate all sessions for the user?

Comment: @EI-01 I'm not sure I follow. If you need to invalidate sessions for a user after they change a password - do it.

Comment: @zerkms the OP wants to keep separate sessions for both mobile and web clients but if the user changes their password on one platform then it should invalidate for all devices.

Comment: @EI-01 okay .....